# How to replace the Activities Overview button with the Applications Menu in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

I currently have Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 installed, however even though I like mostly everything about GNOME 3, I would like to remove the Activities Overview button, and get the Application Menu pull-down menu there instead of it.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this the easiest way you will need to install two extensions by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819).

These are the extensions: [**Applications Menu**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) (which will add back the Applications Menu - this extension is pre-installed so you will only need to activate it, not install it), and [**Activities Configurator**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) (you will need this to easily remove the `Activities Overview` button).

Once you have both installed, have opened the `gnome-tweak-tool`, and are in the settings panel for the `Activities Configurator` (instructions for all these steps are provided in the first link), click the slider which is labelled `Remove Activities Button` in order to set it to `On` rather than its current state `Off`:

[image: <code>Activities Configurator</code> settings panel]

This will remove the `Activities Overview` button and all which will be left in its place will be the `Applications Menu` labelled `Applications` which will have been created when you installed the `Applications Menu` extension.

**And here is the final result!**

[image: Final result]

---

You will still be able to view the Activities Overview if you wish by click on the `Applications Menu` and then on `Activities Overview` at the bottom or by pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd>. And you can of course always reverse these settings as well as disable or completely remove these extensions in the `gnome-tweak-tool`'s `Extensions` section.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Gnome Classic instead of Gnome. The developers have removed the Activities from it (to my dismay).

For Ubuntu you can look here:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-gnome-classic-mode-ubuntu